# how can l write the code when i press the image button display in Edit text android

Tags: android

Excuse me, I have a question how can l write the code when i click on image button send it on edit view with the same pic inside the button
 like the emojicon chat 
note :
the same idea of emojicons  but with my special icons like this picture
like this picture :

[image]

Comment: Please add some code of what you have tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask might help you to improve you question as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you looking for `Spannable`'s? They can be used to insert images into a field that contains plain text in Android. You can view the Google documentation for Spannable's [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

I wrote a code example below that might give you a head start:

```
public CharSequence addImageSpan(CharSequence text){
  SpannableStringBuilder builder=new SpannableStringBuilder(text);

    int resId = R.drawable.emoticonImgResource;

  builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(mContext,resId),
    text.start(), text.length()-1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

  }
  return builder;
}
```